# Desktop distro with installer image less than 700MB?

Tags: distro-recommendation

Previously I'm using Lubuntu because the installer can be burnt in CD.

Now the 16.04 x64 installer image size more than 700MB. Plus, it feel too heavy on my computer.

I'm now using Bodhi Linux but looking for several more choice.

Comment: I'm not looking to make Ubuntu Minimal works in bootable USB.

Comment: I did that too, but if there is available small installer distro, I prefer to use that distro instead and not to roll another ball

Comment: You can burn Ubuntu Minimal CD to a CD. You can also choose *Lubuntu minimal installation* in the *Software selection* screen for a more lightweight desktop. Take a look at this screenshot of the Software selection screen: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vmrp.jpg . Lubuntu minimal installation is the second selection from the bottom.